# how to get only "webpack compiled successfully" debug (line)?

Tags: webpack, cypress

I am currently in the process of optimizing compilation time. After setting `DEBUG` to `"cypress:webpack:stats"`, e.g. in PowerShell:

```
$env:DEBUG="cypress:*"
```

and  I do `cypress run` I see many debug messages and also this line:

```
webpack 5.88.2 compiled successfully in 93049 ms
```

Is it possible to set `DEBUG` some way to get only that line (besides the normal output) without all the other debug messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, not only that line but at least much less other lines:

```
$env:DEBUG="cypress:webpack:stats"
```